# Calling Stored Procedures with Both Nullable Inputs and OUT Parameters in JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

I'm trying to find a way to call an Oracle Stored Procedure through SpringBoot JPA directly via a repository interface.

Other than a few of these sorts of procedures, most of the other data access is already handled by the more standard JPA repository entity methods.  So ideally, I'd like to find a way to do this through the existing repositories.

```
PROCEDURE add_strike (i_party_id                         NUMBER,
                      i_strike_date                      DATE,
                      i_thru_date                        DATE,
                      o_strike_id                        OUT NUMBER);
```

This is being made difficult by two things:

This procedure has some nullable inputs.  From what I can tell, this precludes using @Procedure.  I'm aware of the "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.proc.param_null_passing=true" property, but from what I could see in the Hibernate source, this flag was deprecated and no longer having any effect on the current version of Hibernate.  Is there any way around this as of 2022?  I tried several variations of setting param_null_passing globally, at the QueryHint level, calling the DB procedure directly, using @NamedStoredProcedureQuery, etc.  In all cases, Hibernate would simply not accept null inputs.

```
@Procedure("add_strike")
long addStrikeProcedure(Long partyId, LocalDateTime strikeDate, LocalDateTime thruDate);
```

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The parameter named [thruDate] was null. You need to call ParameterRegistration#enablePassingNulls(true) in order to pass null parameters.

The procedure also has an OUT parameter.  This is making it difficult to use the native Query syntax, as I haven't been able to track down a way to get this to work with the annotated repository interface style @Query( ..., nativeQuery=true ).  Is there a way to write a Query in this form that returns a value via an OUT parameter?

```
@Query(value = "{call add_strike(?1, ?2, ?3, ?4)}", nativeQuery = true)
long addStrikeQuery(Long partyId, LocalDateTime strikeDate, LocalDateTime thruDate, Long out);
```

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADD_STRIKE'

I tried several other variations of the @Query with similar results.  Is there a way to call a procedure like this using @Query to return a value from an OUT parameter?

I'm able to call this procedure successfully using more direct approaches, such as SimpleJdbcCall.  But I was hoping there would be a way to do this through a JPA repository interface to keep things consistent rather than having to split data access across multiple approaches/classes depending on the type of procedures.

But all the information I've found so far says "Use @Procedure if you need to handle OUT parameters" and "Use a native @Query if you need to pass NULL inputs".  Is there a simple, JPA Repository interface friendly way of accomplishing both at the same time?

Comment: It's not a solution to your problem but I don't use Hibernate with Oracle to call procedures. I use http://www.jooq.org/ that generates classes to call the procedures. I know it's not free but if you need to do this a lot it's worth the money.

Comment: Have you got any solution to the problem. I am also stuck at this for a couple of days